# UFW deny all incoming except SSH

Tags: iptables, ufw

I am about to configure firewall with UFW. I am logged in over SSH so I don't know if the terminal will be locked out as soon as I do:

```
 sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

If so, how can I deny all incoming (lock the whole thing down) except SSH and do it all in the same command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, despite the warnings, enabling UFW does not lock out the current session. By default, UFW will block all incoming. To allow SSH, use:

```
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
```

You can also use the `limit` option (note that port 22 is the default SSH port):

```
sudo ufw limit 22/tcp
```

To enable UFW use:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: You can also use the `at` command to issue a "sudo disable UFW" at +5 minutes, so if you do get locked out, you can wait 5 minutes, and be allowed back in ;)